# Creating a command interpreter process and writing to it

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I have been trying to create a cmd.exe from a c++-program and then being able to execute commands **from** the program **inside** the cmd.exe, so I can view the results of the operation in the cmd.exe. `CreateProcessA()` is the function I used:

```
_STARTUPINFOA CMD_StartupInfo = {};
CMD_StartupInfo.cb = sizeof(_STARTUPINFOA);

_PROCESS_INFORMATION CMD_ProcessInfo = {};

CreateProcessA("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
               0,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               FALSE,
               CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               &CMD_StartupInfo,
               &CMD_ProcessInfo);
```

The cmd.exe opened and it looked to be working. Then I thought I'd use `PostMessage()` to pass WM_KEYDOWN messages to the cmd.exe to execute a command. For this function I needed a window handle and it turns out that the process of getting a window handle from a process/thread ID which is obtained from the `CreateProcessA()` is f***ing complicated. You have to loop through all active windows with `EnumWindows()` that requires a callback function which needs to check whether or not the process ID of the current window is the same as the process ID of the process I created.

I did that and it turned out that none of the windows the function iterated over were my window.

So I presume that means that the thread of this process which I created has no windows but I can see a beautiful-looking cmd.exe right there. What is going on? Is this not considered a window? If not, how do I pass messages to the cmd.exe and if yes, how do I get the window handle?

Any help is appreciated (also ideas to do the entire cmd-thing differently).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output

Comment: Windows is intentionally designed to make it hard to access another process' memory, for security reasons. Doesn't matter if you are the one who spawned the process. The EnumWindows method is essentially a hack. It might be easier to attach a console to your own process, then run `cmd` through `system` calls.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. Currently it's not clear if you are using `EnumWindows` correctly, and that may contribute to you not finding the correct window.

Comment: @Lundin How do you attach a console to a process?

Comment: @Mgetz No it does not. system() executes a command but not in the cmd.exe I created

Comment: @WidoSeidel any specific reason you need it to be that CMD? Just curious.

Comment: @Mgetz I need to compile a .cpp file and to do that the environment needs to be initialized and also I want to be able to see the compiling errors

Comment: Ah ok, yeah `system` is definitely not the right tool for that. If you know what the parameters are I'd say use `CreateProcessW` with a batch file and then hijack the `stdout` and `stdin` streams to listen to them

Comment: @WidoSeidel Through the Windows console API... which I remember nothing about, sorry. Been ages since I poked around with that :)

Comment: @Mgetz Any particular reason to use CreateProcessW() over CreateProcessA()? And do you know anything about the "hijacking"

Comment: @WidoSeidel the usual reasons to use the `W` functions on windows: it operates more consistently than the `A` functions do because there is less locale dependence. Also see the handles [in `STARTUPINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-_startupinfoa)

Comment: @Mgetz Ah, I didn't know that

Comment: @WidoSeidel the irony of that is that `CreateProcessW` is one of the few that tries to be [over clever](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090601-00/?p=18083) and has a non-const string parameter as a result of not requiring conversion of the command line buffer

Comment: Forget any Unix bad things in Windows.

Comment: @WidoSeidel see http://dslweb.nwnexus.com/~ast/dload/guicon.htm for how to add a console window to a GUI based application.  It has always annoyed me that there isn't a console that I can use for debugging / logging while developing a GUI based application.

Comment: using spy++, you should at least be able to get the window handle etc. of your created window.  However, running spy++ and attempting to spy on a console window (launched by cmd.exe), I get an error message "Windows will not allow access to the message stream for this window".  Might be a security thing to prevent reverse shells.

Comment: for execute commands - use pipe pair (asynchronous from your side) - write commands to pipe and read result from it

Comment: ShellExecute()?